# How to force "container-fluid" to max out height or stretch when browser is resized

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap there is a CSS style `container-fluid` which we use in our app. The problem is, when the app loads I can see that the div which this CSS style is applied gets this:

```
element.style {
   height: 322px;
}
```

However I tried to use Javascript to set the CSS height of `container-fluid` on app load, the height gets that size, which is actually the initial height of the browser. So the issue is that when I resize the browser there gets a white space that the background of the div which have this `container-fluid` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use !important with that class styling and javascript won't take over this property.

For example:

```
#main {    
  height: 100% !important; 
}
```